# How to make .exe ALWAYS run as admin on ALL PCs

Tags: windows, exe

So I've written a GUI powershell script to prompt the user for the Bitlocker PIN change that should only happen 1x. Changing the default PIN basically.

Using PS2EXE I transformed this into an .exe file using the -noConsole switch so that the cmd prompt window will never appear, only the "script" (.exe) itself

But this .exe program or script NEEDS admin rights always. I have tried writing a manifest file for it, putting it inside the same folder as the .exe itself and the content of the manifest file is a line of XML code, NOTHING ELSE:

Theoretically this should make the .exe always run as admin, but it isn't working. It always runs as standard user.

Since this .exe program will be part of my new system image, I need it to always run as admin, on ANY PC whatsoever, running as standard user cannot be possible at all

So far the only way I could get this to work is to make is I created a shortcut for the exe and the right click, Properties, Advanced, Always Run As Admin or sth along those lines

But this isn't good. I don't want to have to use a shortcut. I want the exe itself to REQUIRE admin rights to run to begin with.

How could I get this to work?

Comment: You realize that even if you get this to work, it's going to ask for an admin password?

Comment: @MarkRansom not sure what you mean. In its script form, it does NOT ask for an admin pw.

Comment: Then you must be running it from a Powershell window that is already admin.

Comment: Yes but it still won't run because I need to right click on it to run it as admin. I want that to be the DEFAAULT behavior of the .exe on all pc's

Comment: Good luck with that.  Microsoft deliberately makes it hard to run as admin so that you won't get viruses.